# NSArray's instance variable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

When I go look at NSArray's interface file, it doesn't declare any instance variable.  So how does NSArray works without having any instance variables?

By the way, in order to look at the header file, go to Xcode, click "File" on the menu item and click "Open Quickly".  Type in NSArray and open the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSArray is an abstract superclass. More specifically, it's what's known as a [Class Cluster](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ClassClusters). Every actual instance of NSArray that you work with is a private, concrete subclass of NSArray.

Comment: hmm…  I guess that's one way of making private classes.